# How to use Abort Controller to abort APIs initiated from inside useEffect but triggered by user action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise

1. I am calling some set of APIs inside the useEffect hook.
2. But incase user clicks on the `cancel` button. I want controller.abort() to trigger to cancel all API calls (let's call this method as `*cancelAllCalls*()`)

Problems : (1) I have to initiate controller.abort() outside useEffect. >> This required controller variable to be accessible inside `*cancelAllCalls()*` - **Not working**

(2) If I try to do a `setState` inside `*cancelAllCalls()*` and add that as a dependency in the `useEffect` to call `controller.abort()`it will still re-initiate the controller and the signal passed to the APIs will also change - **Not working**

Note : I am able to achieve it by adding an eventListner on by `cancel` button inside the useEffect only (& I made sure it happens only once by using a flag) and then calling `controller .abort()` inside it. But I am not quite contented with this approach.

Any suggestions/guidance here?

Comment: It's hard to help you without any code snippets. See [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
function TestComponent(props) {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current= new AbortController;
    return () => (ref.current.abort());
  }, []);

  const cancelAllCalls= ()=>{
    ref.current.abort();
    ref.current= new AbortController();
  }

  // your hooks
  React.useEffect(() => {
     //..
  }, [myVar])

  return ()
}
```

Or like this ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-fetch-tiny-ui-states-g5qd7?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import React from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";
import cpAxios from "cp-axios";

// Note: the related network request will also be aborted

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [cancel, done, result, err] = useAsyncEffect(
    function* () {
      return (yield cpAxios(props.url).timeout(props.timeout)).data;
    },
    { states: true, deps: [props.url] }
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {done ? (err ? err.toString() : JSON.stringify(result)) : "loading..."}
      </div>
      <button onClick={cancel} disabled={done}>
        Cancel async effect
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```